# Several tables in JTable of joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want to display/add/delete data from several table in MVC component, in `JTable` class:

```
class HelloWorldTableHelloWorld extends JTable
{
    function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('code', 'id', $db);
      //parent::__construct('#__fairinfo', 'flight_id', $db);
      //parent::__construct('hotelinfo', 'hotelid', $db);
    }
}
```

Constructor initializes the id's of tables for deletion and edition purpose. I have successfully displayed the data of three tables, but when I performed the deletion operation then only that table data is delete, which is initailized in `JTable` class, but if I add all tables and initialize them in `JTable` it gives me an error.

Comment: not a single expert of joomal 2.5???????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joomla is not designed to work that way. You are meant to use one table file per database table.

In your model you can instantiate all three tables if needed, but each table file should be separate.

In your model do the following:

```
 $tableCode = JTable::getInstance('Code', 'HelloWorldTable');
 $tableFairinfo = JTable::getInstance('Fairinfo', 'HelloWorldTable');
 $tableHotelinfo = JTable::getInstance('Hotelinfo', 'HelloWorldTable');
```

Then you can:

```
 $tableCode->load($id);
```

or

```
 $tableHotelinfo->delete($id);
```

etc;

But instead of messing about with all of this, why don't you give the [component creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) a try?

Comment: componen creater wont help me to to show dta from two tables and then apply CURD opertaion on all data of tables. btw thx a lot to make me clear the things

Comment: Is there any way to do a one-to-many table relationship here?