# Get data from another table into form of Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating a component for Joomla! 2.5 and I have the following MySQL table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `#__table_a` ( 
    id                   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    actividad            VARCHAR( 255 ),
    publish_up           DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    publish_down         DATETIME NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE `#__table_b` ( 
    id                   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_a_id            INT NOT NULL,  /*foreign key to table '#__table_a' field 'id'*/
    hora                 TIME NOT NULL,
    created              DATETIME NOT NULL,
    publish_up           DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    publish_down         DATETIME NOT NULL
 );
```

What I want is that, in the form where I managed data from "`# __table_a`", I need to be able to manage data that is listed in the table "`#__table_b`".

How do I do it?,

Ie where do I do the "query" for such data and to display them in the form?, in the "table_a" model or controller?

Comment: Query should be write in model only.

Comment: I answered this over here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299319/several-tables-in-jtable-of-joomla-2-5?rq=1